# Resend PHP API request in case of failure (retry mechanism)

Tags: php, api, curl

My PHP script is working with multiple external services using API requests and theirs SDKs. It happens, that requests might fail and I would like to implement a retry mechanism.
SDKs don't have this feature built-in and they will just throw an `Exception` if request was not successful.
I've created multiple functions that use SDKs to retrieve / upload required data and now I would like to add retry mechanism if any of SDK requests fail. I could add a piece of code around every SDK call like this:

```
$retry = 0;
while ($retry < 3) {
    try {
        $account = $client->load('account');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $retry++;
    }
}
```

But this means that I will add the same piece of code to every SDK function call and it's going to be a real mess.

Is there any possibility in PHP to create a generic function or some kind of wrapper that will retry executing function if it has failed (thrown an `Exception`)?

P.S. SDKs use `curl` to send requests. Maybe, it's possible to tweak `curl` to implement this kind of retry mechanism?

Comment: The loop will break if an exception occurs.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay 1. It won't break as far as it's `handled` exception (inside try-catch block). 2. It's just an example, there could be hundreds of implementations of the same behavior.